# iOS App bottom menu control

Tags: discussion, feature-request, ios-app

Could it be possible to make a setting on what to view in the bottom control?

Right now it is

Questions | Users | Tags | Ask

I'd like to see **Review** instead of **Users** for example. I click like 100 times a day on Review instead of Users.

Maybe there are more items which could be set in the bottom on personal settings?

Comment: maybe it'd be prudent to request review functionality in the app first?

Comment: Probably indeed, but this don't have to be implemented in first version. I just noted it would be nice?

Comment: ["review queue things will be in the "sooner rather than later" category when we get there"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224156/)