# Please add diamond flag handling to the iOS app

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flags, moderator-tools, ios-app

The iOS app is great, but I can't use it to perform diamond functions like handle flags. I would love to have a table view of all the flags on my site, with the buttons we currently have in the normal flag queue.

Also of use, but much more work, would be the ability to destroy users and such. I would settle for just plain flag handling, though.

Comment: ... so that we can still moderate while careening through a tunnel on a high-speed train.  Or while skydiving.

Comment: No, please add a(n open source) plugin for the Android app that includes mod flag handling. Open Source so we can improve it and add custom stuff (like highlighting of certain phrases for NAA flags). Why I'd like this? Handling maybe ten "easy" NAA flags (those contain certain phrases that are usually only found in crap) takes half a minute.

Comment: You're not getting paid by the flag, man! Take a break once in a while!

Comment: @Pops The best part of waking up, is an empty flag queue...in your cup.

Comment: @Pops Naw, we're just paid by the number of times we incidentally invoke Godwin's law, right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Moderator tools of some kind are on the roadmap, and review queue things will be in the "sooner rather than later" category when we get there.

Comment: Is this true for the Android app too, as I assume it involves new API's?

Comment: @hichris123 yep.