# Are the review queues planned for the iOS app?

Tags: feature-request, review, ios-app

I enjoy reviewing on SO, is it currently possible to review on the iOS app? If not, is it planned to be implemented?

Comment: A comment I posted on the [Android request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215841/add-review-queues-to-android-app): *"This also assumes that Stack Exchange would be alright with implementing API calls to fetch review items and accept responses for those items. Honestly, that sounds a bit sketchy."* - It's highly doubtful that they would ever implement the necessary API calls to allow reviewing from the apps.

Comment: I kinda agree with you animuson, and on my iPad, I'm perfectly happy doing reviews in the mobile browser. This is less good on my iPhone, but maybe I just shouldn't be doing reviews on my phone.

Comment: Also, this seems to have been mentioned on a related question. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224132/please-add-diamond-flag-handling-to-the-ios-app/224156#224156

Comment: I'd love to see this in the iOS app.

Comment: As a mod I'd at least see current queue states from iOS app, and perform basic close / hold / delete questions too.