# Allow mobile users to review posts

Tags: feature-request, review, android-app, ios-app, mobile-app

I have recently discovered reviewing posts and am working towards the respective badges. However, the majority of the time (even now) I use the mobile app, rather than the desktop. Therefore I was very disappointed when I couldn't find a way of reviewing posts while on the app.

Feature request: add in a way for people to review posts while on the app, for both iOS and Android.

Personally, I think that having a button to access this would be best placed [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF2NS.png) in the iOS app, but that's just my opinion.

What do you think? Is this a plausible idea?

Comment: Also, ios dupe: [Are the review queues planned for the iOS app?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/231492/323179)