# Do moderator flags exist as mobile app notifications?

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, mobile-app

Is there any provision to allow the site moderation - more specifically, flags raised - to be available on a mobile app as notification alerts, a la normal Inbox notifications?

Or does a moderator need to have a web browser tab open all the time and manually scan for flags once in a while?

This seems to have been [requested as as feature before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111212/moderator-flag-notifications-should-reach-mobile) but no official status or comment or answer was given, and the request is a couple years old so things may have changed.

Comment: That's not quite the same feature -- it's asking about _on-site_ notifications in the mobile _web_ interface. It predates the native apps. Unless I'm misunderstanding this question.

Comment: Perhaps [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224132/please-add-diamond-flag-handling-to-the-ios-app)?

Comment: @JoshCaswell - my question is about native apps (android specifically, if they are feature-different)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. There is no way to access flags or any other diamond moderator-specific tool through the documented API or through the Android app. The only moderator-specific behavior in the Android app are that close votes are immediate (reopening is not available in the app) and that comment deletion is available in the user interface for everybody's comments.

Flags are not available as notifications, either. The only way to know that there's a flag is to load a page on the site. (I think the rationale is that if you're a mod, you should be mostly on your site, but that doesn't work for multisite mods, or mods on slow sites who also participate on higher-traffic sites.)

I've heard rumors of moderators writing their own polling scripts and routing the information over whatever notification channels. The only one that I've seen shared publicly is [Simon Forsberg's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/97268/desktop-notifications-for-flags-and-queue-items).

Answer (score 5):

No, this isn't a feature in either the iOS or Android apps. Moderators aren't paid by the flag; I just try to check in every so often (at least once a day, usually once an hour or so).

It's theoretically possible to build your own app and push notification infrastructure that just scrapes the page occasionally and checks for changes to the flag indicator, that's probably your best bet if you really want this.