# An option to get app notifications of new mod flags (once mod flag handling is implemented)

Tags: feature-request, flags, notifications, moderator-tools, ios-app

I know that adding moderator flags to the iOS app is on the roadmap from the answer to [Please add diamond flag handling to the iOS app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224132/please-add-diamond-flag-handling-to-the-ios-app). This is a supplemental feature request that I want to get into the request queue for when mod flag handling is ready to be tackled.

Getting a notification of a new flag would make flag handling quite a bit faster. Handling flags in a timely fashion is part of why we have multiple mods. Being able to improve flag handling without adding mods would be a nice efficiency perk.

Obviously it can't be an always-on feature though — **SO mods would mutiny**, to put it mildly. It would be extremely useful on the many smaller SEs though, where flags are a few a day and swift handling makes a disproportionately significant improvement in site quality. For it to be a reasonable feature, it would have to be a default-off switch.

Could we have a flag notification feature in the iOS app, which is default off but can be toggled on, once mod flag handling is added to the app?